# Why does my color change back to black after my CSS3 transition?

Tags: html, css

I have a group of divs set up to slide up when the user scrolls down the page. Once the text has fully "arrived" to their location, the color goes from my defined color back to black.

I cannot figure out why.

I have tried adding !important to the color already.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px; background-color: #fafafa; padding-bottom: 30px;">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="firstcol">
            <center>
                <h3 style="padding-top: 40px; color: #6D1A66 !important;">About Us</h3>
                <p style="padding: 40px; text-align: left !important;">
                </p>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4" id="secondcol">
            <center>
                <h3 style="padding-top: 40px; color: #6D1A66 !important;">Browse Our New Selection</h3>
                <p style="padding: 40px; text-align: left !important;">
                </p>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4" id="thirdcol">
            <center>
                <h3 style="padding-top: 40px; color: #6D1A66 !important;">Come Stop By!</h3>
                <p style="padding: 0 40px 40px 40px; text-align: left !important;">

                </p>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the transition code:

```
.expandUp{
    animation-name: expandUp;
    -webkit-animation-name: expandUp;   

    animation-duration: 1.5s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;

    animation-timing-function: ease;    
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;        

    visibility: visible !important; 
}
```

```css
@keyframes expandUp {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(100%) scale(0.6) scaleY(0.5);
 }
 60%{
  transform: translateY(-7%) scaleY(1);
 }
 75%{
  transform: translateY(3%);
 } 
 100% {
  transform: translateY(0%) scale(1) scaleY(1);
 } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes expandUp {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%) scale(0.6) scaleY(0.5);
 }
 60%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-7%) scaleY(1);
 }
 75%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(3%);
 } 
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scale(1) scaleY(1);
 } 
}
```

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated and this is not enough code to reproduce your issue

Comment: I should have added.... it's the H3 tag's text that goes back to black from #6D1A66.

Comment: What code are you using to animate the divs? That code is probably the problem.

Comment: I added the animation code. Please note the } that is not in the code is NOT in my code either.

Comment: @Kyle1323 [Still not able to reproduce the issue...](https://jsfiddle.net/frx650tL/1/)

Comment: @max That is the only code that is effecting that section of the page.... I can't reproduce it anywhere else either. I guess I'll have to figure something else out.

Comment: @Kyle1323 Sorry to hear that. The problems that can't be isolated are always the most difficult to solve.

Comment: I just tried changing the color from #6D1A66 to "blue" and it stayed blue. Has anyone heard of this issue before? @max

Comment: @Kyle1323 Wait what? Try it with some more hex colors and some more named colors. Does it always fail on hex and always work with named?

Comment: you have probably assigned the css command to class that is removed from the elements once the animation is over. Quick fix: Try to assign color to element using style attribute

Comment: It looks like it only doing it with that specific code code....

Comment: It's only doing it with any code that is close to the color purple..... Not really sure why???

Comment: Even just the color "purple" doesnt work.

Comment: Please post a full working code snippet that reproduce the issue

Comment: @lgson I have posted everything that references that part of the site. I have discovered that its not just that section, it goes through the entire page. I am still looking for the reason.....

Comment: @Kyle1323 You say it only happens with colors that are close to purple? Maybe it's an issue with your monitor... perhaps try running your code on a different device?

Comment: @max I'm using the same color multiple places on the site and they work fine. You can actually watch the color fade to black. I really can't figure it out lol

Comment: I see the flash to black at the end that you're talking about. I'm not sure how to explain that or what is causing it. It doesn't actually seem to be changing code wise.

Comment: Instead of scaleX(1) scaleY(1) you have scale(1) scaleY(1) (no X) which may be confusing the browser.

Comment: Once you go black you can't go back? On a serious note, without the way to reproduce the error, the supplied code is not enough to determine what is causing the change in color. Check your changed color with "inspect element" tool of the browser and see what css is causing the color to be black. CTRL SHIFT I by default.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's a weird "bug" referring to text rendering. And maybe it's hardware dependent too.

I took the fiddle from @MaximillianLaumeister and added **`translateZ(0px)`** to the keyframes' transforms: https://jsfiddle.net/frx650tL/2/

```
@keyframes expandUp {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(100%) scale(0.6) scaleY(0.5) translateZ(0px);
    }
    60%{
        transform: translateY(-7%) scaleY(1) translateZ(0px);
    }
    75%{
        transform: translateY(3%) translateZ(0px);
    }   
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%) scale(1) scaleY(1) translateZ(0px);
    }   
}
```

And I was able to get rid of the darkening effect after the animation finished.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
div {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

this will keep the animated styles as it is after completing the animation. I agree that provided code not enough to recreate the issue but I'm definitely think this will solve your issue.

[more details...](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp)